# Problema con contar caracteres en I/O

Tags: c++17

He probado con un simple programa el contar cuantas veces se repite un caracter. Pero no importa cuantas veces lo revise, no puedo encontrar el error.

- El texto tiene 113 caracteres con la letra 'e'
- El error es que solo cuenta 111 letras 'e'

#### El texto

```
Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate ipsum necessitatibus officia atque quasi itaque repellendus nobis labore. Molestiae error perspiciatis fugiat qui laborum impedit cumque officia nulla corrupti in!
Voluptatum repellendus reprehenderit, soluta assumenda provident est, placeat cumque quam, error totam veritatis rerum distinctio laudantium fugit delectus explicabo debitis magni! Fuga perferendis pariatur libero quia accusantium quaerat quos fugiat!
Illo explicabo error temporibus corrupti dolores vel veritatis at, excepturi quaerat harum itaque, nihil quas numquam iste tempore quisquam veniam necessitatibus quia. Error, at id quo esse nobis accusantium soluta?
Inventore unde saepe rerum facere accusantium, ducimus recusandae, voluptatum dolore nesciunt quas sapiente illum corrupti ea provident iure ipsam in a accusamus, aperiam totam? Alias reprehenderit beatae deleniti nesciunt quam?
Architecto ipsa autem iste? Magni tenetur consequuntur harum, doloremque, praesentium ipsum modi laudantium sequi explicabo asperiores nam beatae ullam quae. Eligendi et quaerat porro earum officia non voluptates ad nostrum!
```

#### Mi codigo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

// lee los contenidos en "filename" y cuenta las repeticiones de "match"
void fileSearch(const std::string& filename, char match)
{
    std::ifstream content{ filename };
    int matchCounter{ };

    if (!content)
    {
        std::cerr << "File not found." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    while (content)
    {
        std::string word;
        content >> word;
        for (auto letter : word)
        {
            if (letter == match) matchCounter++;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Se encontraron " << matchCounter << " coincidencias sobre: '" << match << "'" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char digito;

    std::cout << "Escriba un digito/caracter a buscar dentro del archivo: ";
    std::cin >> digito;

    fileSearch("algo.txt", digito);

    return 0;
}
```

Le pido a alguien que me explique que sucede con esos dos caracteres, llevo todo el dia debugeando y no entiendo donde faltan.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es, simplemente, que únicamente estás buscando las coincidencias en minúsculas. Si te fijas verás que el texto tiene dos palabras con una E mayúscula:

- Error
- Eligendi

Tu estás buscando coincidencias con el caracter `e`, cuyo código ASCII es 0x65, en cambio la `E` mayúscula tiene el código ascii 0x45, y coincidirás conmigo que `0x65 != 0x45`.

La solución sería buscar ambos caracteres en el fichero:

```
char lowerChar = tolower(match);
char upperChar = toupper(match);

// ...

if ((letter == lowerChar) || (letter == upperChar)) matchCounter++;
```